# run specific javascript for each page

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I've put this code  in `public Form1`

```
//Wait for the page to finish loading (all resources will have been loaded, rendering is likely still happening)
        chromeBrowser.LoadingStateChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            //Wait for the Page to finish loading
            if (args.IsLoading == false)
            { 
                string script = string.Format("javascript code");
                chromeBrowser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);
            }
        };
```

And it works fine for the first page loaded. Now I'd need to execute another javascript code when is loaded the next page (2nd page). I can do it through URL or loaded order of page

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/73.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_LoadingStateChangedEventArgs_Browser.htm http://cefsharp.github.io/api/73.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_IBrowser_MainFrame.htm if you check url using something like args.Browser.MainFrame.Url

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much